# If we connect resistor in parallel of supernode, what current will the resistor carry?

Tags: circuit-analysis

If the resistor or impedance is being connected in parallel to supernode, then what current value will be across that resistor or impedance?[image: when the resistance is parallel to supernode, can we neglect it directly?]

Comment: diagram?????????

Comment: Do you understand ohms law?

Comment: Define supernode... Never heard that in 20 years experience in electrical....

Comment: @soosai_steven, it's a very well-known term in circuit theory.

Comment: @soosaisteven. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernode_(circuit). Vote to close has been denied.

Comment: I'm very familiar with Kcl and Kvl, but never used the term supernode in any of my work before. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we define a supernode around two nodes connected by a voltage source, in order to facilitate a solution to a circuit by the modified nodal analysis.

If you connect a resistor across a voltage source, you get a current through it determined by Ohm's Law, regardless of whether we're analyzing the circuit with MNA, mesh analysis, or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

If a resistor is connected across the terminals of a supernode, then the resistor terminals will remain at the voltage across the terminals of the supernode. The resistor will allow current to flow between the terminals of the supernode. The current is dependent on the value of the resistor. The current can be calculated using Ohm's Law:
**I = V/R**

Comment: "leak power across the terminals"  ? ?

Comment: If I am correct, a voltage applied across a resistor will create a current that's size is dependent on the size of the resistor. Power is dependent on current and voltage.

Comment: that could make an improvement to your answer (edit your answer).  Use the word Value rather than "size".